# How do I set up SIP voice calling in Empathy?

Tags: empathy, voip

I would like to use Empathy for Internet voice chat, but I do not see an option under the Empathy Accounts menu to create a SIP account.

How do I set up Internet voice calling in Empathy?

Comment: I think you need `telepathy-sofiasip` package installed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 13.04 (and presumably 12.10), telepathy relies on rakia instead of sofiasip, and you need the Ubuntu account SIP module. In other words :

```
sudo apt-get install telepathy-rakia account-plugin-sip
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm on 13.04 and this was definitely the solution.

Comment: This still works on 18.04

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 there is apparently no `account-plugin-sip` anymore, but if you only install `telepathy-rakia` it will pull the needed dependencies automagically for you and then it works (you can configure a SIP service).

Answer (score 2):

According to https://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#How_can_I_connect_to_my_SIP_account.3F
you need to install the `telepathy-sofiasip` from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Then, you will be able to add SIP accounts to Empathy from the list of protocols in the Empathy Accounts dialog.

Comment: This was a correct answer, but 12.10 took away the accounts dialog and replaced it with something that doesn't seem to detect `telepathy-sofiasip`

Comment: I also have a problem with 12.10: I was able to setup my SIP account from the account list, but when I try to start a call, I have to select a contact, I can not enter a sip: URL directly. On the other hand, the only available contacts are my google-chat contacts, and I can not add contacts to the SIP account :-(