# How to set up VOIP in ubuntu

Tags: networking, cisco, voip, sip

I am running a small business unit on agency recruitments. Need to know about setting up a VOIP service to call USA/Canada..

We have around 20 phones on line and we operate from bangalore.

What tool/software is used for this ?? What are the hardware requirements?

Appreciate your help.

Alvin

Comment: You can check this thread also about setting up VOIP with Empathy: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37556/how-do-i-set-up-sip-voice-calling-in-empathy

Answer (score 2):

**VoIP and messaging on the Ubuntu desktop**

Ubuntu's principal application for this is called Empathy, and provides many features in addition to simple voice, such as video chat.

There are several other end-user applications which you may also consider:

- Jitsi is the most extensive and versatile open source VoIP and
  messaging solution
- Ekiga was previously the default VoIP solution in Ubuntu
- KPhone the definitive KDE desktop voice application
- Twinkle looks good with KDE desktop; no video chat
- Qutecom also fits KDE desktop better; successor to wengophone, but no
  tie-in to one provider
- Gizmo5 (on Medibuntu) designed primarily for use with a Gizmo phone
  account, but can be configured to use alternative voice services.

[Check the source for more information and learn more and all about your needs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VoIP)